# questions about my c-programming code, compilator issues

Tags: c

Hey i seem to get issues runnin the code, should i have a int main() or is that not needed in this situation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int tal1=8, tal2=3
     float svar;
    svar=tal1/tal2;
    printf("%",svar);
    svar=tal1%tal2;
    printf("%f",svar);

      return 0;
    }
```

edit: i still have a issue after using int main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int tal1=8, tal2=3
 float svar;
svar=tal1/tal2;
printf("%",svar);
svar=tal1%tal2;
printf("%f",svar);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you always need a `main` function

Comment: Yes, `main` is mandatory for a normal program that is not a library

Comment: ok, but i still have a issue when i use int main,

Comment: `printf("%",svar);`->`printf("%f",svar);`

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after `tal2=3`

Comment: Seems like you need to back up a little bit, do a C tutorial, read a C book, take a C programming class?

Comment: Also please make it a habit to code in English when you pick variable names and write comments. If you use your native language, it all turns into a mess when you need to include libraries, which will be written in English (called 'Swenglish'/'Svengelska' here in Sweden). Plus, you might at some point need to ask help from the people at SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `main` function for a normal program.

The prototype of `main` for C should be

```
int main(void)   
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

From C99 onwards it is possible to skip the `return 0`. The compiler shall automatically infer it.

Comment: this is the final solution i got:

Answer (score 0):

Correct code Should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int tal1=8, tal2=3;
    float svar;

    svar=tal1/tal2;
    printf("%f",svar);
    svar=tal1%tal2;
    printf("%f",svar);
    return 0;
}
```